# Will updating to Java 1.8 from 1.7 to use Heroku cause any issues

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, heroku

I'm running Yosemite on a Mac and I want to use Heroku but it requires Java 1.8 and I'm currently running 1.7. I'm currently running Eclipse Mars and and Apache Tomcat 8.0.24. I want to know if I will have any issues if I upgrade. Will I need to redirect my libraries in Eclipse? Also, will I need to redirect my path to JAVA_HOME once I upgrade?

Comment: Try to find out.  I have an issue when updating but it may be related to what I have.

Comment: Wait, since when did Heroku ever depend on Java?  This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Heroku does not require Java 8, but one of the tutorials does https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#introduction

Answer (score 0):

Heroku does not require Java 8. But one of the [getting started tutorials](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#introduction) does, and I suspect this is what you are using.

If you would prefer to stick with Java 7, you could try following this [Spring MVC guide for Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-spring-mvc-hibernate).

Comment: Thanks I will look into that. I was able to deploy a war app without installing Java 8.